# why did the trafficlight doesnt work

Tags: android

I did this code and want to make a traffic light on and off several times and then stop and choose one of the two lights at random, but the program does the operation, but does not show the changing lights as the operation does

```
private ImageView redLight;
private ImageView greenLight;
private Button Button;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.traffic_lights);


    redLight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.red_light);
    greenLight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.green_light);
    Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);


    // Assign click listeners to buttons
    Button.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == Button) {
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (flag == 0) {
                turnOnRedLight();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                Log.i("Traffic", "Red");
                flag = 1;
            } else {
                turnOnGreenLight();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                Log.i("Traffic", "Green");
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}



private void turnOnRedLight() {
    redLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_on);
}

private void turnOnGreenLight() {
    greenLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_on);
}
```

}

Comment: What does it do then?

Answer (score 1):

You are only sleeping for 100ms so you probably aren't seeing the lights change. Change that to something like 1000 or maybe even 500 and you will probably see the change

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Also, a couple notes

1. Although with this code it may not be a problem, sleeping on the `UI Thread` usually isn't a good idea. Use a `Thread` and update `UI` with `runOnUiThread()`, use `AsyncTask`, or `Handler`.
2. Don't name your `Button` "Button". Name it something that isn't an Android keyword like `button`, `btn`, `startButton`, `startBtn`, or something similar.
3. When distinguishing between which `Button` was clicked use the `Button` `id` instead of the `Object`. So you would want to change it to

   ```
    @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {   
   if (v.getId() == (R.id.start_button)) {
   ```

you could also use a `switch` statement here but not important.